# External URL Link as Featured Images

Tags: featured-post

How do set  post thumbnail (featured image) from an external URL without uploading the image to  WordPress media library.

Comment: What have you tried so far. Please edit your question to show your efforts and code you have written, working or not

Comment: As @PieterGoosen said, can you provide a sample code you have tried already? If not the question can fall in "Do it for me" category.

Answer (score 1):

Recommending a plugin is not how it works in this community, but there is a plugin which is lightweight and does exactly what you need.

Check the plugin in [WP Remote Thumbnail](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-remote-thumbnail/)